# Hg pager extension doesn't work for 'blame'

Tags: mercurial, pager, hgrc, blame

I am using Merucrial with the `pager` extension, and I am trying to configure out to use the pager for `blame`, but it's not working.

I have in my `.hgrc` file:

```
[extensions]
pager = 

[pager]
pager = less -FRX
attend = diff, status, help, log, blame
```

The other commands - `diff`, `status`, `help`, and `log` are correctly routed through the pager, but `blame` is not. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blame` is an alias for `annotate`. If you specify `annotate` rather than `blame` in the `.hgrc`, it works fine.

I guess the `pager.attend` attribute does not accept aliases, it needs the name of the original command.

I [filed a bug](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3991) for this.